# Analogue of $(f\cdot\nabla)f=\frac12\nabla|f|^2-f\times\operatorname{curl}f$ in the two-dimensional case

Tags: vector-analysis, tensor-products, fluid-dynamics, curl

If $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^3$ is open and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R^3$ is differentiable, there is the identity $$(f\cdot\nabla)f=\frac12\nabla|f|^2-f\times\operatorname{curl}f\tag1,$$ where $$\operatorname{curl}f:=\nabla\times f.$$

> Is there an analogue of $(1)$ in the two-dimensional case?

I think we could rewrite $(1)$ using the alternating tensor product $\nabla\otimes f-f\otimes\nabla$ in place of $\operatorname{curl}f$ and obtain a natural analogue in this way. In any case, I'd really like to know whether $(1)$ can be written in this way.

Comment: Try calculating this in the case $f=<f_1,f_2,0>$.

Comment: @Paul It's not that I'm not able to derive a corresponding identity. But how is $\operatorname{curl}f$ defined in the two-dimensional case? Surely, doing what you suggested, yields $\operatorname{curl}f=(0,0,\partial_1f_2-\partial_2f_1)$. I know that. My question is whether there is a notion (other than $\operatorname{curl}$) so that $(1)$ holds in the two-dimensional (or even an arbitrary dimension) as well. That's why I've specifically asked for a possible formulation using the tensor product, which I would treat in the sense of the dyadic product here.

Comment: It's not just the curl that is not defined in 2-d; it's also the cross product.  Sometimes the z-component for the curl you mention is called the scalar rotation in 2-dimensions, but then you have to handle the cross product as well.  Fortunately, the cross product of a vector in the z-direction with another vector is always in the xy-plane.  The reason I said it would be best to calculate the values in this way, is that you might be able to identify the term as a tensor product (although a differential form looks more natural in this case).

Comment: The main reason that there is not a natural notion for a vector curl in 2-d is that rotation happens without an axis in 2-d (in general, in even-dimensional spaces, rotation may not have an axis of rotation).  Since curl is in the direction of the axis of rotation, there is no vector that can makes sense here.

Comment: @Paul Okay, including the cartesian product, if $f:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ does not depend on the third argument and $f_3=0$, then $$f\times\operatorname{curl}f=\begin{pmatrix}\displaystyle f_2\left(\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}-\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}\right)\\\displaystyle f_1\left(\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}-\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}\right)\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$ If I got you right, you've got some identification as a tensor product in mind?

Comment: @Paul I'd still be interested in a response.